# Bash: Check all values of an associative array is equal to

Tags: arrays, bash, foreach

I have an associative array that is dynamically created. I don't know how many items there will be or what their names will be but this is an example I have created:-

```
declare -A MDARRAY
MDARRAY[md126]="clean"
MDARRAY[md127]="degraded"
```

I would like to compare the value of each array item against a couple of strings. For example, the required result would be similar to :-

```
if [ "$MDARRAY[md126]" != "clean" || "$MDARRAY[md126]" != "active" && "$MDARRAY[md127]" != "clean" || "$MDARRAY[md127]" != "active" ]; then
...
else
...
fi
```

If there were 5 array items it would check all 5 and if any one of them doesn't equal 'clean' or 'active' the first code block would match else the second.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `${MDARRAY[@]}` to get all the values, and a `for` loop to check each of them.

Comment: Thanks, I was struggling to understand how to keep track of the issues so created an incrementing counter if there was a match. Have posted my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

My solution with the help from Karoly:-

```
clean=0
for i in "${!MDARRAY[@]}"; do
    # Compare the state of the devices
    if [ "${MDARRAY[$i]}" != "clean" ] && [ "${MDARRAY[$i]}" != "active" ] ; then
        # Increment error count
        ((clean=clean+1))
        # Add device name to array if error
        BADARRAY=(${BADARRAY[@]} $i)
    fi
done
```